# Problem understanding the subspace topology of a given topology

Tags: general-topology

I just started learning about the subspace topology. This is the definition and an example that I have in my book:

*Given a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and a subset $S$ of $X$, the subspace topology on $S$ is defined by $\tau_s= \{S \cap U, U \in \tau\}$.*

*Example: If we consider $X$, $Y \subset X$, and  $\tau^Y=\{A \subset X | Y \subset A\} \cup \{ \varnothing\}$, it's easy to see that $(\tau^Y)_Z=\tau^{Y \cap Z}$. So if $Y \cap Z = \varnothing$ then $(\tau^Y)_Z $ is the indiscrete topology, and if $Y \cap Z = Z$ then $(\tau^Y)_Z $ is the discrete topology.*

1. I don't see why $(\tau^Y)_Z=\tau^{Y \cap Z}$. I tried to prove it but I couldn't see how the two topologies have the same open sets.
2. I get that if $Y \cap Z = \varnothing$ then $(\tau^Y)_Z $ is the discrete topology, because $\varnothing \subset O$ for all $O \subset X$, but I dont understand why if $Y \cap Z = Z$ then $(\tau^Y)_Z $ is the trivial topology. Shouldn't it be just $\tau^Z=\{A \subset X | Z \subset A\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(\tau^Y)_Z\subset\tau^{Y \cap Z}$, but we couldn't say $\tau^{Y \cap Z}\subset (\tau^Y)_Z$

Now take any $Z\cap U\in (\tau^Y)_Z$, then $(Y\cap Z)\subset (Z\cap U) $ since $Y\subset U$. Then $Z\cap U\in\tau^{Y \cap Z}$.So $(\tau^Y)_Z\subset\tau^{Y \cap Z}$.

Now say  $Z\subsetneqq X$ and since $(Y\cap Z)\subset X  $ we can take  $X\in \tau^{Y \cap Z}$. Since  $A\subset Z$ for all $A\in (\tau^Y)_Z$, but $X\not\subset Z$. So  $X\notin (\tau^Y)_Z$.

2. $\tau^Y=\{A:Y\subset A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}\Rightarrow (\tau^Y)_Z=\{U\cap Z:U\in \tau^Y\}=\{A\cap Z:Y\subset A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$

Now if $ Y\cap Z=Z$, then $Z\subset Y$. So if $Y\subset A$, then $Z\subset Y\subset A$ and  $Z\cap A=Z$.   Then $(\tau^Y)_Z=\{A\cap Z:Y\subset A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}=\{Z,\emptyset\}$

Comment: Thanks!  Btw i think there's a typo. In the final of the first paragraph, did you mean *but $X \not \subset Z$.* instead of  *but $X \subset Z$*?